# C# JSON Serialization of Dictionary into {key:value, ...} instead of {key:key, value:value, ...}

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dictionary

Is it possible to serialize a .Net Dictionary<Key,Value> into JSON with **DataContractJsonSerializer** that is of the format:

```
{
  key0:value0,
  key1:value1,
  ...
}
```

I use Dictionary <K,V>, because there is not predefined structure of the inputs.

I'm interesting just for **DataContractJsonSerializer** result! I've already found a "Surrogate" example, but there is an additional "data" in the output, and if the dictionary <K, String> is, the escaping is false too.

---

I've found the solution, what a needed! First of all, a serializable "dictionary" class:
(Of course, this sample works just in one way, but I dont't need deserialization)

```
[Serializable]
public class MyJsonDictionary<K, V> : ISerializable {
    Dictionary<K, V> dict = new Dictionary<K, V>();

    public MyJsonDictionary() { }

    protected MyJsonDictionary( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context ) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context ) {
        foreach( K key in dict.Keys ) {
            info.AddValue( key.ToString(), dict[ key ] );
        }
    }

    public void Add( K key, V value ) {
        dict.Add( key, value );
    }

    public V this[ K index ] {
        set { dict[ index ] = value; }
        get { return dict[ index ]; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static String Serialize( Object data ) {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer( data.GetType() );
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject( ms, data );

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString( ms.ToArray() );
    }

    public static void Main() {
        MyJsonDictionary<String, Object> result = new MyJsonDictionary<String, Object>();
        result["foo"] = "bar";
        result["Name"] = "John Doe";
        result["Age"] = 32;
        MyJsonDictionary<String, Object> address = new MyJsonDictionary<String, Object>();
        result["Address"] = address;
        address["Street"] = "30 Rockefeller Plaza";
        address["City"] = "New York City";
        address["State"] = "NY";

        Console.WriteLine( Serialize( result ) );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
      "foo":"bar",
      "Name":"John Doe",
      "Age":32,
      "Address":{
         "__type":"MyJsonDictionaryOfstringanyType:#Json_Dictionary_Test",
         "Street":"30 Rockefeller Plaza",
         "City":"New York City",
         "State":"NY"
      }
   }
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to limit to `DataContractJsonSerializer` ? Every time I've done a comparison (which is several times : I'm very "into" my serializers) this is the least preferable JSON tool for .NET; I always look at JavaScriptSerializer or JSON.Net

Comment: In what context are you using this? That is is this a WCF app, ASP.NET app or something else. Are you using the DataContractJsonSerilizer in such as way that you're calling the WriteObject yourself or is some framework doing it for you?

Comment: What's not clear in your post is that you want 1 JSON object with properties (and their values) being the name/value pairs in the dictionary. Either that or something is wrong since it can't be a JSON array since you can't have a JSON array where each element in the array has different property names. So can you be clear about the actual format you're looking to get?

Comment: Hi Shiv Kumar: I call the WriteObject, why? And in one run I have the elements with the same structure, but this structure is not predefined, that's why I can't do a class for it. The DataContractJsonSerializer has company-reasons... :)

Comment: @Shiv Kumar: Yes, it is definitely possible to have a JSON array with different property names. This actually happens every time you choose to omit properties with null values from the JSON.

Comment: Anyone figured out the opposite?  As in, how to get it to deserialize `MyJsonDictionary` properly?

Comment: [You shouldn't answer your own question in an edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit). Instead actually add an answer, please edit your question and add the answer, as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 84):

Json.NET does this...

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
values.Add("key1", "value1");
values.Add("key2", "value2");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
// {
//   "key1": "value1",
//   "key2": "value2"
// }
```

More examples: **[Serializing Collections with Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)**

Comment: 2nd line should be `string values = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);`

Answer (score 23):

In .NET 5 and later, you can simply write:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new();
        values.Add("key1", "value1");
        values.Add("key2", "value2");

        string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(values);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

to get `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`.

No external dependency is [needed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

Answer (score 16):

use property `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` on `DataContractJsonSerializer` and set it to `true`.

Does the job :)

Comment: how can you set that settings for the default behavior of wcf when serializing the http response ?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!  I had to use `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;` in `WebApiConfig.cs`.

Comment: Exact answer to the question

Comment: The property `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5 from 2012, it seems.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using out of the box MVC4 with this code (note the two parameters inside `ToDictionary`)

```
 var result = new JsonResult()
 {
     Data = new
     {
         partials = GetPartials(data.Partials).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y=> y.Value)
     }
 };
```

I get what's expected:

```
{"partials":{"cartSummary":"\u003cb\u003eCART SUMMARY\u003c/b\u003e"}}
```

---

**Important**: WebAPI in MVC4 uses JSON.NET serialization out of the box, but the standard web `JsonResult` action result doesn't. Therefore I recommend using a custom ActionResult to force JSON.NET serialization. You can also get nice formatting

Here's a simple actionresult `JsonNetResult`

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx

You'll see the difference (and can make sure you're using the right one) when serializing a date:

Microsoft way:

```
 {"wireTime":"\/Date(1355627201572)\/"}
```

JSON.NET way:

```
 {"wireTime":"2012-12-15T19:07:03.5247384-08:00"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in the latest version of DataContractJsonSerializer.  See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558686/datacontractjsonserializer-should-serialize-dictionary-k-v-as-a-json-associative-array

The current suggested workaround is to use the JavaScriptSerializer as Mark suggested above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The MyJsonDictionary class worked well for me EXCEPT that the resultant output is XML encoded - so "0" becomes *"0030*".
I am currently stuck at .NET 3.5,  as are many others, so many of the other solutions are not available to me.
"Turns the pictures" upside down and realized I could never convince Microsoft to give me the format I wanted but...
                string json = XmlConvert.DecodeName(xmlencodedJson);

TADA!
The result is what you would expect to see - regular human readable and non-XML encoded.
Works in .NET 3.5.