# How to get a JSON object from a DataContract .NET with dynamic names

Tags: .net, json, datacontracts

I have the following object:

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{
   [DataMember]
   Dictionary<string,string> B {get; set;}
}
```

With the default serialization using DataContractJsonSerializer I get the following JSON

```
{ B : [{"Key":"Rable","Value":"RableRable"}] }
```

But what I want to get is the following

```
{ B : [ { "Rable" : "RableRable" } ] }
```

being the "Rable" the key of an Dictionary Entry and the "RableRable" the value.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861138/c-sharp-json-serialization-of-dictionary-into-keyvalue-instead-of-keyk

Comment: Thank you robyaw, your comment solved my problem