# WCF JSON IDictionary serialization

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization, dictionary

Consider following WCF method that recieves and returns data in JSON.

```
public IDictionary<string, string> GetData(IDictionary<string, string> input)
{
    input.Add("newKey","newValue");
    input.Add("newKey2","newValue2");
    return input;
}
```

Is there a way how to pass & retrieve JSON in format:

```
[{"newKey":"newValue","newKey2":"newValue2"}]
```

instead of:

```
[{"Key":"newKey","Value":"newValue"},
{"Key":"newKey2","Value":"newValue2"}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# JSON Serialization of Dictionary into {key:value, ...} instead of {key:key, value:value, ...}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861138/c-sharp-json-serialization-of-dictionary-into-keyvalue-instead-of-keyk)

Comment: @DanielA.White: As far as I understand the other thread, its about calling custom serializer. That is not the issue since the goal is to let the WCF service handle it itself

Comment: I think what @DanielA.White is saying is that if you declare your own `OneWayDictionary` like the example and use it instead of `IDictionary` as the method return type, it should serialize it properly to `{key: value}` in the output.  But that only serializes it; what I need to know is how to get it to also DEserialize (which the example ignores because it doesn't need).