# Convert to Nested JSON C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to convert Dictionary key,value Object to nested JSON, but I'm unable to do so.
I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject);`
Can someone please help me out. I have something like this

`"operation":"pay"
"order.amount":"100"
"order.currency":"PKR"`

amount and currency should be nested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# JSON Serialization of Dictionary into {key:value, ...} instead of {key:key, value:value, ...}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861138/c-sharp-json-serialization-of-dictionary-into-keyvalue-instead-of-keyk)

Comment: would you mind sharing your Nested Object structure?