# Generate JSON from Dictionary<Path, Value>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have Dictionary, which contains json paths and values:

```
Logging.Console.IncludeScopes = true
Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft = "Warning"
Logging.LogLevel.System= "Warning"
Sort.TypeOrder = "asc"
```

I want to generate json from this dictionary.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Sort": {
    "TypeOrder": [
      "asc"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but maybe this gives you an idea anyhow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4861138/6996150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Comment: Object can be generated out of box by any tool like `NewtonSoft.Json` byt question here how the `TypeOrder` is converted to an array? Can the existing class structure be updated to add the JsonConverter attribute over property or class?

Comment: @johey it's about generating json from simple key value dictionary, I have path in key.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I've seen it, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your key contains dynamic path for Jobject so you could use a recursive function to achieve this.

Finally serialize the output dictionary which should produce the desired json.

See here

```
private static void CreateJSONFromDictionary(string[] keys, int index, string value, IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    var key = keys[index];

    if (keys.Length > index + 1)
    {
        object childObj;
        IDictionary<string, object> nestedDict;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out childObj))
        {
            nestedDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)childObj;
        }
        else
        {
            nestedDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict[key] = nestedDict;
        }

        CreateJSONFromDictionary(keys, index + 1, value, nestedDict);

    }
    else
    {
        dict[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Use this

```
var output = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
     var keys = kvp.Key.Split('.');
     CreateJSONFromDictionary(keys, 0, kvp.Value, output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize the whole Logging object. My suggestion is to create a custom class for logging settings, use it for both setting log and output JSON.

```
public class LoggingSettings
{
    public bool includeScopes;
    public LogLevel logLevel;
    public int day;
}

var settings = new LoggingSettings
        {
            includeScopes = true,
            typeOrder = "asc",
            logLevel = new LogLevel
            {
                microsoft = "Warning",
                system = "Warning"
            }
        };
```

Serialization:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Usage when setting log:

```
Logging.Console.IncludeScopes = settings.includeScopes;
Logging.LogLevel.Microsoft = settings.logLevel.Microsoft;
Logging.LogLevel.System= settings.logLevel.System;
Sort.TypeOrder = settings.typeOrder;
```

Comment: I said, it's Dictionary, not object. Logging.Console.IncludeScopes is a key and true is a value of it in Dictionary.

Comment: @Dadroid He's saying that you shouldn't be using the dictionary for serialization because it's not going to do what you want it to do.